# Sending raw data to printer using WritePrinter

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, printing

I am trying to send raw bytes to a printer. I have tried various printers and nothing seems to work. `OpenPrinter` returns a valid handle and both `StartDocPrinter` and `StartPagePrinter` succeed. Even `WritePrinter` succeeds and writer as many bytes as there was passed in and a print job appears in the spooler window. All appears like a success and still nothing gets printed.

I know writing raw bytes to printer is really printer-specific so I have tried printing to a file and sending those file's contents to `WritePrinter`. All appears fine and still no printout. What could be wrong? All sample code I have found so far does this 100% the same as I did. Here is the code:

```
if (OpenPrinter(printerName, &printer, NULL))
{
    DOC_INFO_1 docInfo = {L"Print Job", NULL, L"RAW"};

    DWORD printJob = StartDocPrinter(printer, 1, (LPBYTE) &docInfo);

    if (printJob != 0)
    {
        if (StartPagePrinter(printer))
        {
            DWORD written = 0;

            if (WritePrinter(printer, (LPVOID) (LPCSTR) str, str.GetLength(), &written))
            {
            }

            EndPagePrinter(printer);
        }

        EndDocPrinter(printer);
    }

    ClosePrinter(printer);
}
```

[Edit] Printer: Canon iP4200

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with the code.  Not documenting the printer make and model is a mistake.

Comment: Edited question. Printer is Canon iP4200. Why vote to close already?

Comment: That's a cheap ink-jet printer, it only costs 9 dollars :)  Not the kind of budget that allows a manufacturer to put a controller in the printer itself.

Comment: Hm... pardon my ignorance, but this helps me how exactly? I suppose cheap printers are not worthy of an answer. Now seriously... so what if the printer has no "controller"? Why does that prevent me to send raw data to it? I am sure a printer driver sends something, why can't I?

Comment: You need to pass the printer specific configuration information completely in `str` in a language understood by the printer...likely not easily done with such a cheap printer.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - Thanks! Do you know why sending the entire file previously generated by print-to-file for this specific printer would not work? This seems like exactly the RAW input the printer would expect, isn't it?

Comment: You're sending the data as if it was in the RAW format, however, what format was generated by print-to-file? PS? PCL? Some Windows specific format? "In Windows, the default format when you print to file is `.prn`."

Comment: @sixlettervariables, all that changes when you select "print to file" is the destination for the bits. It still goes through the print driver to get translated properly.

Comment: @MarkRansom: then RAW may be appropriate, but I wonder if `"PRN"` as the format would work. I can recall using `"text"` with some dot matrix printers years ago. One other possibility is `str.GetLength()` is skipping nul characters.

Comment: @sixlettervariables - str.GetLength() can be safely ignored. That's just one way I tried to implement it. I have other versions of code sending proper byte arrays, not strings.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: `PRN` does not work as "doc type" - just tried it  - if that's what you meant.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: PRN isn't a valid data type unless the printer has its own print processor that supports it.  Examples of standard Windows data types would be RAW, TEXT, NT EMF 1.003, and so forth.  .prn is simply the default file extension for print-to-file.  It is not a data type.

Comment: @CareyGregory: it was a SWAG. I guess the question remains, what is the data type of the prn output for his printer...

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I couldn't say without being able to examine the printer properties.  It's a cheap printer but it's also a photo printer, so it likely has its own print processor and custom data type.

Comment: @wpfwannabe: Go to printer properties, advanced tab, print processor.  See what the data type is set to.  Set yours to match in the docInfo struct.

Comment: @CareyGregory: Just been there and I get `Print processor dialog cannot be displayed.`. Still, I am not strictly looking for a specific solution for my particular printer but rather a generic one. How would I go about and do all of this programmatically? When I enumerate printers using `EnumeratePrinters` and `PRINTER_INFO_2` I get `RAW` for `pDatatype` for this printer.

Comment: Well, the results from EnumeratePrinters should be good enough, but something's seriously wrong with that printer or the machine if it can't display that dialog.  Your solution looks sound to me in a generic sense.  I would try it with another printer.  You don't have to actually have the printer.  Just install an HP LaserJet or something like that and set the port to FILE: or NUL: